# Как автоматически генерировать ярлыки латиницей (транслитом) если админка WordPress на русском

Tags: wordpress

Как известно, если админка WordPress на русском, то при создании новой страницы ее ярлык генерируется кириллицей.

А как сделать чтобы ярлык генерировался латиницей т.е. транслитом?

Есть может какой то hook?

Answer (score 1):

Установите плагин [cyr2lat](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/). Он решает именно такую задачу.